# Enabling activex in multiple browsers

Tags: browser, activex

I've created a small activex control, it works fine in IE, surprisingly enough it doesn't seem to work in any other browser. I know that firefox has got an add-on to enable activex, my question is if there is any general API for all browsers to suggest the client to install. Other than that, what options do I have for enabling my activex component on multiple browsers?

Comment: Your only option to be cross-browser is to avoid ActiveX.

Comment: I have no other choice as I am seeking security privileges I couldn't achieve otherwise

Answer (score 3):

ActiveX is a Windows-only, Internet Explorer only API. You can perhaps get an limited support in Firefox but most browsers won't support it. I'd really consider using something else like Flash, Javascript/HTML or even Silverlight which are supported across browsers and platforms.

ActiveX is still actively developed by Microsoft but has been commonly used for virus/malware delivery so users are (rightfully) very suspicious of applications written using it.

Comment: It's still currently used in SharePoint to work directly with office.

Comment: ActiveX remains a supported technology. The claim that it's often "used for malware" delivery is rather misleading. It's more correct to say that buggy ActiveX controls are often abused by malicious sites. See http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2009/07/15/internet-explorer-s-activex-security-mitigations-in-use.aspx for more info.

Comment: Spyware on IE6 was pretty much exclusively due to ActiveX. It may be actively supported but it has no real future in the modern web.